Cómo desplegar mi proyecto Angular 18 con SSR en Hostinger
Estoy buscando la manera de hostear mi web desarrollada en Angular 18 y usar SSR.
En mi proyecto se han creado los siguientes archivos en la carpeta dist al hacer el build:

He podido lanzar el proyecto con SSR en firebase sin problemas con esta configuración:

Mi proyecto funciona en hostinger si ingreso en la carpeta raiz el contenido de dist/browser, pero quiero lanzar mi proyecto con SSR y estoy bastante perdido buscando información al correcto sobre cómo hacerlo.
Son dos cuestiones las que tengo en mente:

¿Se puede hostear en Hostinger?
¿Cómo se puede hostear el proyecto con SSR en Hostinger u otra plataforma?


que servidor web maneja hostinger? [tag:apache]?

Finalmente he hosteado mi proyecto con ssr en Vercel sin mucha complicación. En hostinger no ha sido posible.
Para hacerlo en Vercel he enlazado con mi proyecto de github. El propio Vercel hace el despliegue de la aplicación y puedes hacer que la ejecute con el comando que quieres (en este caso el que lanza la aplicación con ssr).

me encuentro con el mismo problema o duda que tu, en mi local lo puedo iniciar con ssr , pero al desplegarlo en vercel, solo lo veo sin ssr en ver código fuente de la página, he probado a modificar los script en el package, pero igual, si me pudieras indicar, te lo agradezco
